# It Runs in the Family

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I am slipp'ry, I can slide;
Burn you with a simple lie;
Burn you 'cause I'm feeling high.

See my sister boil and blister;
She can burn you, make you flow;
Burn you 'cause she's feeling low.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically...

> ...you’re a **base**!

I am slipp'ry I can slide;

> Soap is a base, I believe, and it’s slippery.

Burn you with a simple lie;

> A reference to **lye**, a substance with a pH of 13, according to Google.

Burn you 'cause I'm feeling high.

> Bases trend toward *high* pH measurements. Substances at the extremes can be harmful to exposed skin.

See my sister boil and blister;

> Your sister happens to be an *acid*.

She can burn you, make you flow;

> Strong acids can cause burns.

Burn you 'cause she's feeling low

> Acids rank *low* on the pH scale. Lower numbers indicate greater acidity.

Comment: This is right. I'll mark it as accepted as soon as I'm done trippin' so hard. :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Coldness, or warmness?

I am slipp'ry I can slide;

> Ice?

Burn you with a simple lie;

> Freezer burnt.

Burn you 'cause I'm feeling high.

> I am not sure becuase the temperature would be low, but it might be a trick. But maybe snow?

See my sister boil and blister;

> Heat.

She can burn you, make you flow;

> When you get a burn.

Burn you 'cause she's feeling low.

> Again, maybe a trick, but maybe fire.

Comment: Not bad, but today is not "opposite day." :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you be

> The **Sun $\&$ Moon**?

`I am slipp'ry I can slide;` 
 `Burn you with a simple lie;` 
 `Burn you 'cause I'm feeling high.`

> This paragraph talks about the **moon**. 
>  
>  It **slides** in the sky and looks like **ice** from it's white colour (hence **slipp'ry**). It can burn you with a simple lie: it is **daytime** and you might get **sunburnt** (the moon often appears at night). Lastly, humans have to [thank the stars](https://www.space.com/35276-humans-made-of-stardust-galaxy-life-elements.html) for our existence, and they only twinkle (or **burn**) at night with the moon; it is the only time where we can see them clearly.

`See my sister boil and blister.` 
 `She can burn you, make you flow.` 
 `Burn you 'cause she's feeling low.`

> This pargraph talks about the **sun**. 
>  
>  It **boils and blisters** because it is literally a giant ball of **plasma**. You can get **sunburnt** and perhaps need to go for a swim (hence make you **flow**). Lastly, you can appear to look burnt under a **red** sky (because you would look red from light; you would look burnt, perhaps), which [only happens](https://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/wilderness-resources/blogs/why-the-sky-turns-red-and-orange-at-sunset) during a **sunset** (when the sun is **low** in the sky).

---

**Title:**

`It Runs in the Family`

> The family might be the [**Solar System**](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/solar-system/our-solar-system/overview/) (a family of **planets**) where the sun and the moon are. The moon *runs* (**orbits**) around the Earth, and the sun *runs* around the centre of the galaxy.